# Make a different IF depending on which page the user came from

Tags: php

Basically, I have 3 pages. 
There's a page that can be accessed by the other two.

I need to make an IF on the third page, because i need to create 2 different queries, depending on the page the user came from.

I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but failed doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is on page 1 overwrite or create session page:

```
$_SESSION['page'] = 'page1';
```

If the user is on page 2 overwrite or create session page:

```
$_SESSION['page'] = 'page2';
```

Now on the third page :

```
if($_SESSION['page'] == 'page1') {
//do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```